# Application errors when sorting in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to get data to sort with VBA. This range will change so it needs to be determine each time the macro is run. If I use the code below, I get a 1004 application error.

```
Sub CaseRevToDo()

Set WBToDo = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ToDo")
Set TblToDo = WBToDo.ListObjects("Table11")
Set WBConReport = Workbooks.Add
WBToDo.Activate

WBToDo.ListObjects("Table11").Range.AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:="<=" & Date + 30, _
   Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="Overdue"

WBToDo.Application.Union(Columns(2), Columns(3), Columns(9)).Copy

WBConReport.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:C").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=True, Transpose:=False
WBConReport.Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("A").ColumnWidth = 20
WBConReport.Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("C").ColumnWidth = 10

WBConReport.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A9", Range("C9").End(xlDown)).Sort key1:=Range("C9"), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo  *** Error on this line


End Sub
```

I have tried to specify the range *for this worksheet* like below:

```
WBConReport.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A9:C114").Sort key1:=Range("C9"), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo
```

But then I get an error saying that my sort reference is not valid. The issue seems to be how I am referencing the range, but I can't find it.

Comment: Qualify the workbook/worksheet that the `Range` is on.

Comment: You should also qualify the workbook/worksheet that `Columns` are in/on in `Columns(2), Columns(3), Columns(9)`.

Comment: @BigBen, ok. Can you explain what you mean exactly by "Qualify"? I set the workbook/worksheet to be the workbook that was added at the beginning of the macro but I must misunderstand what that does. The workbook with the columns are set to a different workbook.

Comment: `key1:=Range("C9")`... "qualify" meaning specify the workbook/worksheet that `Range("C9")` is on. Here you have not specified, so there is an implicit `ActiveSheet`.

Comment: Best practice whenever you use `Range` or `Cells` or `Rows` or `Columns` is to make sure there is a reference to the worksheet/workbook they are in/on. That is "qualifying."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
With WBConReport.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    .Range("A9", .Range("C9").End(xlDown)).Sort key1:=Range("C9"), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo
End With
```

You have to specify ("qualify") exactly where each range belongs to.  In your code, you have to explicitly specify that "A9" and "Range("C9").End(xlDown)" belong to BConReport.Worksheets("Sheet1")